# Manjaro update: kernel not updating

Tags: kernel, manjaro, pacman

Recently I did an update and which seemed to contained an horrendous amount of bugs. After fixing most of these now i a faced with `pacman` telling `linux 4.16.2-2` is being used. However `uname` is reporting `linux 4.15.17-1`.

I have obviously tried rebooting and `updating grub` but the image is nowhere to be found.

edit: Also mkinitcpio seems to only see the old kernel too.

Comment: When rebooting after a kernel upgrade, you can select the kernel to boot into (new or old) in the Bio bootup, its called the grub boot menu. Do you see the two versions there, and if so, which version is default?

Comment: Nope. As I said the image is not on /boot so when updating grub it doesn't add the listing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i may have solved it.

For some reason when installing the `linux` package, `pacman` reports it is reinstalling `linux416-4.16.2-2` at the beginning but the logs show from `mkinitcpi` `4.15.17-1` is installing. But when specifically selecting `linux416-4.16.2-2` it shows it installing for the first time and logs seem correct.

This is very weird they must be an issue with the package. Its even stranger that `pacman -Syy` still did not select the new kernel either.

Going to reboot now, fingers crossed it works! **edit:** it works like a charm :)